# Java paintComponent as a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, list, shapes, paintcomponent

Don't know if it was a very specific title, but I have already asked this question but has gone dead.
I am trying to execute paintComponent() so I can draw rectangles, triangles and more with the class being a JComponent.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Design extends JComponent {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<ShapeWrapper> shapesDraw = new ArrayList<ShapeWrapper>();
private List<ShapeWrapper> shapesFill = new ArrayList<ShapeWrapper>();

GraphicsDevice gd =     GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int screenWidth = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
int screenHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(ShapeWrapper s : shapesDraw){
        g2d.setColor(s.color);
        g2d.draw(s.shape);
    }
    for(ShapeWrapper s : shapesFill){
        g2d.setColor(s.color);
        g2d.fill(s.shape);
    }
}

public void drawRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
    shapesDraw.add(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
    repaint();
}

public void fillRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height) {
    shapesFill.add(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
    repaint();
}

public void drawTriangle(int leftX, int topX, int rightX, int leftY, int topY, int rightY) {
    shapesDraw.add(new Polygon(
            new int[]{leftX, topX, rightX},
            new int[]{leftY, topY, rightY},
            3));
    repaint();
}

public void fillTriangle(int leftX, int topX, int rightX, int leftY, int topY, int rightY) {
    shapesFill.add(new Polygon(
            new int[]{leftX, topX, rightX},
            new int[]{leftY, topY, rightY},
            3));
    repaint();
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public int getWidth() {
    return screenWidth;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return screenHeight;
}

}

class ShapeWrapper {

    Color color;
    Shape shape;

    public ShapeWrapper(Color color , Shape shape){
        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
}
```

As shown above, everything works perfectly fine, except for being able to choose a colour.
I want to be able to define the rectangles and triangles with their respective positions and lengths but also want to add a colour with it.

But I get an error.

The error says:

**The method add(ShapeWrapper) in the type List< ShapeWrapper > is not applicable for the arguments (Rectangle)**

And:

**The method add(ShapeWrapper) in the type List< ShapeWrapper > is not applicable for the arguments (Polygon)**

Please help! I am so stressed trying to figure this out as it is blocking me from doing many things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty basic...`Shape` is not a type of `ShapeWrapper`, therefore it can't be added to a `List` decalred as `List<ShapeWrapper>`

What you should be doing instead of

```
shapesDraw.add(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
```

is something more like...

```
shapesDraw.add(new ShapeWrapper(Color.BLACK, new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height)));
```

The same goes for your `...Triangle` methods.  You need to wrap the resulting `Polygon` in a `ShapeWrapper` before trying to add it to the `List`

Comment: You sir... Kiss me...
It works, PERFECTLY, couldn't thank you anymore.

Comment: Not unless you are buying drinks ... and lots of drinks ... ;) Glad it worked ;)

Comment: Hahahaha, yes.
Reasons were so I could simplify my coding so if I put paint inside a JComponent, it is a lot easier so then I can just add it right into a JPanel.

Thankyou again.

EDIT:

I think you answered my other question about the same class last week :D

Comment: Yeah, the concept seems familiar ;)